# Associations in Ext js?

Tags: extjs

Help to understand these associations.
I just can not think of how to work with them, how to link models?

There is a modal window to edit the record, you edit - you save - the request goes to the server (1), but there is a second tab where coordinates are added, added - saved and the request should go to the server (2).

I can not solve this problem in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://moduscreate.com/associations-in-ext-js-5/ explains ExtJS associations with a very good example and code snippet.